# DM631 16 channel LED driver

Tags: datasheet

After a bit of advice as reading a datasheet on the DM631, this is a 16 channel constant current LED driver, datasheet can be found here http://www.siti.com.tw/product/spec/LED/DM631.pdf

Now the DM631 uses a supply of 3.3V to 5V and it states on the datasheet "DM631 is a 16-channel constant current sink LED driver"

The datasheet also states "Maximum output voltage: 17V"

[image]

Basically my application requires 12V being supplied to an RGB LED strip.

As I understand it the outputs on the DM631 (which are kind of inputs as they sink current) will be happy as long as the 17V maximum voltage and maximum current rating is not exceeded?

Best regards,

Ant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **As I understand it the outputs on the DM631 (which are kind of inputs as they sink current) will be happy as long as the 17V maximum voltage and maximum current rating is not exceeded?**

Almost. If you set the DM631 to supply 20 mA (3kΩ between REXT and GND), a LED strip that needs 80 mA will not work as expected. The DM631 may be happy but you and your LEDs may not be.

Comment: Of course so just set resistor accordingly to supply enough current for the LED strip.  Thanks for confirming 12V will be ok.